# How to programmatically login into a website that does not return an html response using c#? It hangs when calling GetResponse()

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, httpwebrequest

I am trying to programmatically login into a website ("http://www.smscountry.com") using C#, but the program hangs at the second GetResponse() request, where I try to login by POST method and filling the form fields.

```
        public String GetWebContent(String username, String password)
        {

        //The URL of the Login Form of the website
        String urlSignin = "http://www.smscountry.com/";

        //The action URL of the Login Form of the website on Submit
        String urlLogin = "http://www.smscountry.com/LoginCheck.asp?msg=";

        //Initializes the Uri object of the URLs
        Uri uriSignin = new Uri(urlSignin);
        Uri uriLogin = new Uri(urlLogin);

        //Hashtable to store the form details
        Hashtable formData = new Hashtable();
        formData.Add("UTC", new Hashtable());
        formData.Add("txt_Username", new Hashtable());
        formData.Add("txt_Password", new Hashtable());

        ((Hashtable)formData["UTC"])["value"] = -330;
        ((Hashtable)formData["txt_Username"])["value"] = username;
        ((Hashtable)formData["txt_Password"])["value"] = password;

        //Initializing the data for the post action
        String postData = "";

        foreach (string name in formData.Keys)
        {
              postData += "&" + name + "=" + ((Hashtable)formData[name])["value"];
        }
        postData = postData.Substring(1);

        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

        HttpWebRequest webReq;
        HttpWebResponse webResp;

        //To store the cookies of the response objects to be used for the next request
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

        String responseString = "";

        try
        {
            //Getting response for the Signin page  
            webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlSignin);
            webResp = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();

            //Storing response cookies to be used in the next request
            cookies.Add(webResp.Cookies);

            //Storing ASPSESSION cookie that appears in the Response header Set-Cookie to be used in the next request
            string sessionCookie = webResp.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
            responseString = new StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            string respCookie = sessionCookie.Substring(0, sessionCookie.IndexOf(';'));
            char[] separator  = {'='};
            string[] cookieValues = respCookie.Split(separator);
            cookies.Add(new Cookie(cookieValues[0], cookieValues[1], "/", "www.smscountry.com"));

            //Initializing the request object for log in
            webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlLogin);
            webReq.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            webReq.Referer = urlSignin;
            webReq.KeepAlive = true;
            webReq.Method = "POST";
            webReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
            webReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            webReq.CookieContainer = cookies;
            webReq.Timeout = 30000;
            webReq.ReadWriteTimeout = 60000;


            //Get the response for the request to log in
            //PROBLEM OCCURS HERE - THE CODE DOES NOT EXECUTE FURTHER
            webResp = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();
            responseString = new StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            webResp.Close();
            return responseString;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;

        }

    }
```

I don't understand what the problem is. I think it might have something to do with the page getting redirected an not returning an html response, but I am not completely sure. Is there a solution to this problem? Or is there any other way I can login into this particular website?

Answer (score 4):

You need to send your data before you can get your response.  Igor saw you were setting the content length of the request but rather than set the content length to 0, you need to send your content to the server:

```
...
webReq.GetRequestStream().write( data, 0, data.Length );
webReq.GetRequestStream().close();
webResp = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();
responseString = new StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
...
```

The reason you're not getting a response is because the server is waiting for you to send data.Length number of bytes.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the following line: `webReq.ContentLength = data.Length;` Here, you set the length of you POST request **body** to something greater than zero, while your actual body is empty; all you're trying to send is the header. Replace that line with the `webReq.ContentLength = 0;` and your'e done.